# How to check if cursor is on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

On clicking on a link I show a pop up. Here is my pop up code

```
<div class='' id="custom-popover">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-title">Popover left</h3>
    <div class="popover-content" id="details-container">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also add some html code using jquery when pop up show. Now I want to check if cursor is on this pop over or if user is hovering over this pop up and then I show an alert message otherwise hide the popup. How can I do this? I tried something like this

```
var isHovered = $('#custom-popover').is(":hover");
if (isHovered){
alert("msg"); 
} else {
 $('#custom-popover').hide();
 }
```

But this is not working. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use global variable:

```
var cursorOnDiv = false;

$(document).on({
        mouseenter:function(){ cursorOnDiv = true; },
        mouseleave:function(){ cursorOnDiv = false; },
    }, 
   '#yourDivId'
);
```

and check him

Answer (score 1):

Some thing like this,

```
$( "#custom-popover" ).mouseover(function() {
     $('#custom-popover').hide();
});
```

the function `is()` as per [doc](http://api.jquery.com/is/) is often useful inside callbacks, such as event handlers.
This function runs only once as it is not a callback. So in order to detect hover events use call backs.

You can have even like this if you want to have enter and leave both,

```
$( "custom-popover" )
.mouseenter(function() {

})
.mouseleave(function() {

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
$("#custom-popover").hover(
   function() {
       $("#custom-popover").show();
   },
   function() {
       $("#custom-popover").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you ask:

```
$("#custom-popover").hover(
   function() {
       alert("Hovering now");
       $("#custom-popover").show();
   },
   function() {
       $("#custom-popover").hide();
});
```

You stored a value whether `#custom-popover` is being hovered or not at the time of execution, you did not bind an `eventListener` (`hover`) for the cause.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**

```
if($('#custom-popover:hover'))
{
       alert("msg");
}
else 
{
      $('#custom-popover').hide();
}
```